# Packet dump / hex view format for byte[] to text file

Tags: c#

I want to convert a packet (byte[]) into a hex dump view on a text file but it got messy.

Here is a picture.

[image]

I was looping on the main `byte[]` until I reach mod of 16 (excluding 0) but then if the last line isn't a factor of 16 then ill end up with ASCII representation shifted to the left

I did try several solutions but non is really decent, so I considered it a blind spot and thought I could use some help :)

Also I could use some help on how to check if that character has an ascii representation or should I just replace it with '.'

```
    using (var sw = File.AppendText(Path))
    {
        sw.WriteLine("[Packet Logged at {0} with direction {1}] with length {2} and type {3}",
            DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString().Replace("PM", string.Empty).Replace("AM", string.Empty).Replace(" ", string.Empty),
            ReadWrite.ReadString(Packet,Packet.Length-8,8) == "removed for privacy" ? "Server->Client" : "Client -> Server",
            BitConverter.ToUInt16(Packet, 0), BitConverter.ToUInt16(Packet, 2));
        for (int i = 0; i < Packet.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i%16 == 0 && i != 0)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                sw.Write(Packet[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Taken from http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36747/Quick-and-Dirty-HexDump-of-a-Byte-Array:

```
using System.Text;

namespace HexDump  
{
    class Utils
    {
        public static string HexDump(byte[] bytes, int bytesPerLine = 16)
        {
            if (bytes == null) return "<null>";
            int bytesLength = bytes.Length;

            char[] HexChars = "0123456789ABCDEF".ToCharArray();

            int firstHexColumn =
                  8                   // 8 characters for the address
                + 3;                  // 3 spaces

            int firstCharColumn = firstHexColumn
                + bytesPerLine * 3       // - 2 digit for the hexadecimal value and 1 space
                + (bytesPerLine - 1) / 8 // - 1 extra space every 8 characters from the 9th
                + 2;                  // 2 spaces 

            int lineLength = firstCharColumn
                + bytesPerLine           // - characters to show the ascii value
                + Environment.NewLine.Length; // Carriage return and line feed (should normally be 2)

            char[] line = (new String(' ', lineLength - 2) + Environment.NewLine).ToCharArray();
            int expectedLines = (bytesLength + bytesPerLine - 1) / bytesPerLine;
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(expectedLines * lineLength);

            for (int i = 0; i < bytesLength; i += bytesPerLine)
            {
                line[0] = HexChars[(i >> 28) & 0xF];
                line[1] = HexChars[(i >> 24) & 0xF];
                line[2] = HexChars[(i >> 20) & 0xF];
                line[3] = HexChars[(i >> 16) & 0xF];
                line[4] = HexChars[(i >> 12) & 0xF];
                line[5] = HexChars[(i >> 8) & 0xF];
                line[6] = HexChars[(i >> 4) & 0xF];
                line[7] = HexChars[(i >> 0) & 0xF];

                int hexColumn = firstHexColumn;
                int charColumn = firstCharColumn;

                for (int j = 0; j < bytesPerLine; j++)
                {
                    if (j > 0 && (j & 7) == 0) hexColumn++;
                    if (i + j >= bytesLength)
                    {
                        line[hexColumn] = ' ';
                        line[hexColumn + 1] = ' ';
                        line[charColumn] = ' ';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        byte b = bytes[i + j];
                        line[hexColumn] = HexChars[(b >> 4) & 0xF];
                        line[hexColumn + 1] = HexChars[b & 0xF];
                        line[charColumn] = asciiSymbol( b );
                    }
                    hexColumn += 3;
                    charColumn++;
                }
                result.Append(line);
            }
            return result.ToString();
        }
        static char asciiSymbol( byte val )
        {
            if( val < 32 ) return '.';  // Non-printable ASCII
            if( val < 127 ) return (char)val;   // Normal ASCII
            // Handle the hole in Latin-1
            if( val == 127 ) return '.';
            if( val < 0x90 ) return "€.‚ƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š‹Œ.Ž."[ val & 0xF ];
            if( val < 0xA0 ) return ".‘’“”•–—˜™š›œ.žŸ"[ val & 0xF ];
            if( val == 0xAD ) return '.';   // Soft hyphen: this symbol is zero-width even in monospace fonts
            return (char)val;   // Normal Latin-1
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this solution for dumping binary data:

```
public static class BinaryVisualiser
{
    public static string FormatAsHex(ReadOnlySpan<byte> data)
    {
        byte ReplaceControlCharacterWithDot(byte character) 
            => character < 31 || character >= 127 ? (byte)46 /* dot */ : character;
        byte[] ReplaceControlCharactersWithDots(byte[] characters) 
            => characters.Select(ReplaceControlCharacterWithDot).ToArray();

        var result = new StringBuilder();
        const int lineWidth = 16;
        for (var pos = 0; pos < data.Length;)
        {
            var line = data.Slice(pos, Math.Min(lineWidth, data.Length - pos)).ToArray();
            var asHex = string.Join(" ", line.Select(v => v.ToString("X2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));
            asHex += new string(' ', lineWidth * 3 - 1 - asHex.Length);
            var asCharacters = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ReplaceControlCharactersWithDots(line));
            result.Append(FormattableString.Invariant($"{pos:X4} {asHex} {asCharacters}\n"));
            pos += line.Length;
        }
        return result.ToString();
    }
}
```

Note that this implementation leverages `Span` from C# 7.2 and requires the `System.Memory` NuGet package from Microsoft.

The output is formatted like this:

```
0000 EF BB BF 48 65 6C 6C 6F 2C 20 53 74 61 63 6B 20 ...Hello, Stack
0010 4F 76 65 72 66 6C 6F 77 21                      Overflow!
```

Update: configurable byte width.

```
public static string FormatAsHex(ReadOnlySpan<byte> data, int lineWidth = 16, int byteWidth = 1)
{
    byte ReplaceControlCharacterWithDot(byte character) => character < 31 || character >= 127 ? (byte)46 /* dot */ : character;
    byte[] ReplaceControlCharactersWithDots(byte[] characters) => characters.Select(ReplaceControlCharacterWithDot).ToArray();
    IEnumerable<BigInteger> Chunk(IReadOnlyList<byte> source, int size) => source.Select((item, index) => source.Skip(size * index).Take(size).ToArray()).TakeWhile(bucket => bucket.Any()).Select(e => new BigInteger(e));

    var result = new StringBuilder();
    for(var pos = 0; pos < data.Length;)
    {
        var line = data.Slice(pos, Math.Min(lineWidth * byteWidth, data.Length - pos)).ToArray();
        var asHex = string.Join(" ", Chunk(line, byteWidth).Select(v => v.ToString("X" + byteWidth * 2, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));
        asHex += new string(' ', lineWidth * (byteWidth * 2 + 1) - 1 - asHex.Length);
        var asCharacters = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ReplaceControlCharactersWithDots(line));
        result.Append(Invariant($"{pos:X4} {asHex} {asCharacters}\n"));
        pos += line.Length;
    }
    return result.ToString();
}
```

Which allows (encoded as big-endian UTF-16):

```
0000 4800 6500 6C00 6C00 6F00 2C00 .H.e.l.l.o.,
000C 2000 5300 7400 6100 6300 6B00 . .S.t.a.c.k
0018 2000 4F00 7600 6500 7200 6600 . .O.v.e.r.f
0024 6C00 6F00 7700                .l.o.w
```

Answer (score -1):

- Yes partition 2 is the bootable partition with 80
- The size of partition for the image above  is 2056237 bytes
- dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdx bs=512 skip=2265165 count=1028160

The alignment doesn't matter for the end sector , at least not for performance reasons . Alignment of the start sectors affects in the partition; alignmengt of the last sectore only afftets the last few sectors of the partition , if at all. So sectors are numberes from 0 and the fdisk is suggesting the last sector on your disk which has above results.

hope this was helpful.